# jquery UI dialog opens multiple times

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, load

Im having an issue where the my jquery UI dialog loads multiple times on top of itself:

```
click -> opens dialog(1 time) -> close dialog
click - > opens dialog(2 times) -> close dialog
click - > opens dialog(4 times) -> close dialog
click - > opens dialog(8 times) -> close dialog
```

Exactly what is described here: [Why does my modal jQuery dialog open multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122088/why-does-my-modal-jquery-dialog-open-multiple-times)

I following solution worked for that person but it did not work for me. The solution that worked for that person was to:

1) initialize the dialog outside the function 
2) open only on the successful callback from load()

As you can see I do both things in the following code but the problem still persists. Please help:
(Btw the general structure is I load a dialog on the click of a link. Then when the Register button inside that dialog is clicked, I load another small confirmation dialog on top of it with an OK button that closes both dialogs.)

```
$(document).ready(){
   var $registerDialogHandle = null;
    var $registerStatusDialogHandle = null;

    $registerDialogHandle = $('<div></div>').html("").dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true,  width: 470, height: 552,
        buttons: {
            "Register": function () {
                if ($('#registerForm').validate().form()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        ...ajax settings...
                        success: function () {
                            openInDialog($registerStatusDialogHandle, "/Account/RegisterStatus");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $registerStatusDialogHandle = $('<div></div>').html("").dialog({
        autoOpen: false, modal: true, width: 365, height: 165,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $registerDialogHandle.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('.registerLink').live("click", function () {
        openInDialog($registerDialogHandle, "/Account/Register?path=_RegisterPartial");
    });
} /*End of document.ready()*/

function openInDialog(dialog, target) {
    var $url = target;
    var $dialog = dialog;
    $dialog.empty();
    $dialog.dialog("option", "position", "center").load($url, function () {
         $dialog.dialog("open");
    });
}
```

Comment: Since you are not re-creating the dialogs, you don't need to remove them. Is this code inside of some other function that gets ran more than once?

Comment: ok I removed the remove() call.  And no it is not inside any other function. Everything is directly inside $(document).ready except the openInDialog function which is directly outside it. I downloaded a visual studio extension that matches js brackets to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work ok here, if I change the `.remove()` calls to `.hide()` calls:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/s6SxE/

Comment: I finally figured this out. 

It was loading duplicate because of this line:

openInDialog($registerDialogHandle, "/Account/Register?path=_RegisterPartial");

The problem was with the partial view itself, I had loaded that script into the layout page AND the partial view so the duplication was due to the script itself being present in 2 places.

Thanks a lot for your help, the jsfiddle helped very much to isolate the problem to something completeley different.

ciao

Comment: Ah. Makes sense.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add destroy()

```
$.confirm({
    title: "Caution!",
    content: "Delete?",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
        text: "Not",
        },
        somethingElse: {
        text: "Yes",
        btnClass: "btn-blue",
        keys: ["enter", "shift"],
        action: function () {
          //Something also!
        },
        },
    },
    }).destroy()
```